# Ubuntu 20.10 is booting too slow

Tags: boot, server, partitioning, mount, services

`systemd-analyze critical-chain` output :

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 15.659s
└─multi-user.target @1min 15.659s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @36.601s +39.055s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @36.497s +99ms
      └─nss-user-lookup.target @36.342s
```

`systemd-analyze blame` output:

```
39.055s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
31.827s mysql.service                                        
17.410s php7.4-fpm.service                                   
14.512s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
12.495s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
12.206s dev-sda5.device                                      
11.538s upower.service                                       
10.699s snapd.service                                        
10.341s udisks2.service                                      
 7.203s dev-loop1.device                                     
 7.054s dev-loop8.device                                     
 7.038s dev-loop4.device                                     
 7.012s dev-loop3.device                                     
 6.976s dev-loop10.device                                    
 6.929s dev-loop7.device                                     
 6.831s dev-loop11.device                                    
 6.809s nginx.service                                        
 6.805s dev-loop14.device                                    
 6.640s dev-loop17.device                                    
 6.574s dev-loop16.device                                    
 6.202s dev-loop6.device                                     
 6.118s NetworkManager.service                               
 5.641s dev-loop12.device                                    
 5.538s dev-loop15.device                                    
 5.364s polkit.service                                       
 5.221s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
 5.038s dev-loop2.device                                     
 4.996s avahi-daemon.service                                 
 4.991s bluetooth.service                                    
 4.871s dev-loop0.device                                     
 4.831s dev-loop5.device                                     
 4.822s dev-loop13.device                                    
 4.611s dev-loop9.device                                     
 4.272s switcheroo-control.service                           
 4.268s thermald.service                                     
 4.261s wpa_supplicant.service                               
 3.742s fwupd.service                                        
 3.340s systemd-udevd.service                                
 3.188s valet-dns.service                                    
 3.182s ModemManager.service
```

`systemd-analyze time` output:

```
Startup finished in 5.990s (kernel) + 1min 16.615s (userspace) = 1min 22.605s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 15.659s in userspace
```

Comment: Please describe your hardware.

Comment: nss-user-lookup.target: Do you use a user or group lookup database? Most folks do not.

Comment: what you mean describe hardware ? @Soren

Comment: no i did't use  user or group lookup database

Answer (score 0):

i have enable my boot disk to SSD old one was booted in HDD that what make it too slow